# Does ubuntu come with java installed already?

Tags: java

If so how do I disable it? Whats a good easy to use anti-virus protection that my parents can use?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please read http://askubuntu.com/faq to see what kind of questions you can ask here and how to ask them. Bear in mind: This is not a forum and each question has to be specific.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think so. If I remember correctly I had to install it. If i'm mistaken, and you got it packaged to go then you should be able to remove it with the software center tool

Comment: Upvoting, I see no reason for a downvote on this question which takes away reputation from the answerer.